# WPF automatic trajectory of a point

Tags: wpf, translation, repair

how can I create a application with WPF that can i make a point automatic trajectory on a repair (x,y) ?

1. Choose the leaving point coordinations
2. choose the arrived point coordinations
3. choose the type of trajectory (straight, uniform) ??

Thank you.

Comment: what kind of trajectory you are interested in? do you have any algorithm for the same? are there any constants ie. gravity etc.?

Comment: hello, i want to add a something (a tile for example) with motion on my Grid.

Comment: it is bit difficult to visualize the same, appreciated if you could elaborate the same and support with some examples/pictures etc.